# Rails creates weird mysql requests in RACK_ENV=production

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

We are trying to migrate from rails 4 to rails 5 and
have an error, where it says we have a null violation for one of our fields: created_at
in this code:

```
version_set.each_with_index do |version_from_set, index|
  ...
  version_name = version_from_set['version_name']
  new_version = Version.new
  new_version.name = version_name
  new_version.save
  ...
end
```

Error:

> ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (Mysql2::Error: Field 'created_at' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO versions (updated_at) VALUES ('2020-02-25 10:55:50')) We are thinking about upgrading mysql - but not convinced that this is the issue. And it's not easy to upgrade it in AWS Elastic Beanstalk Schema.db

Its working fine with RACK_ENV=development but error appear in RACK_ENV=production.

Error with stack of requests:
[image]

1. Error
2. Requests should be the same but every request was cut of of one parameter
   and in the last request there are only one parameter.

This is how it looks in development mode. All parameters was provided:

[image]

We desperate. We spend couple weeks trying to track this error. Any suggestions?

Model Version:

```
class Version < ApplicationRecord
  include ResourceAccess
  include HtmlToPlainText

  has_many :users
  has_many :content_items
  belongs_to :mailing
  has_one :campaign, through: :mailing
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams

  validates :name, {presence: true}
  ... (here only methods)
end
```

Comment: are you using PaperTrail gem ?, if so, that table belongs to that gem. You should go to https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md and look for breaking changes between versions, check the version you have and see if there are any. If so, you might need to do what they suggest to fix it, or perhaps update to a newer version ?. Anyway, just go to that file and see if you find anything helpful. Good luck.

Comment: No=( We don't use it.

Comment: Can you please show the code for your Version model?

Comment: There are more than 5000 rows there. I can't provide all of them( But I added beginning of this file. What should i try to find?